# MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [insert] on [test.tours]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[mongodb error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z63mh.png)

Hi everyone, I am using MongoDb and got this error. Could someone help me solve this issue.

Comment: All error messages are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
In the MongoDB > Database Access > Database User > Edit > Built-in Role > and Added Read and write to any database